# How to do variable substitution in Kubernetes manifests?

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes and planning to do continuous deployment of my apps with Kubernetes manifests.

I'd like to have my app defined as a `Deployment` and a `Service` in a manifest, and have my CD system run `kubectl apply -f` on the manifest file.

However, our current setup is to tag our Docker images with the SHA of the git commit for that version of the app.

Is there a Kubernetes-native way to express the image tag as a variable, and have the CD system set that variable to the correct git SHA?

Comment: I believe no.  But this kind of meta-programmimg is what languages like Jsonnet are intended to tackle.

Comment: you can work around this by pushing two tags for the same image build, the sha-commit as well as the latest , and use the latest in kubernetes yaml , this way you have all the commit tags just in case you need them later , and you always pull the latest tag on deployment trigger

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [helm](/questions/tagged/helm) charts in this case, where you separate between the skeleton of templates (or what you called maniest) and its values which are changed from release to another.

In **templates/deployment.yaml** :

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ template "nginx.name" . }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
```

And in **values.yaml** :

```
image:
  repository: nginx
  tag: 1.11.0
```

See the full example [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/examples/nginx)

Comment: so whats the difference between updating values.yml vs updating the deployment yml

Comment: For this case it could work to pass the tag name into the helm command via a --set parameter without needing to modify a values.yaml

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would this allow the CD process to catch any updates to the manifest? For example, if the developer changes something about the `Deployment`, like the resource limits on the pods. I want it to update not just the tag but the whole manifest.

Comment: comment of @RyanDawson is great. Please check out helm.. deep dive into it, today before tomorrow.